# Updating a map that is nested a couple layers in lists in clojure

Tags: data-structures, clojure, functional-programming

I'm new to functional programming, and I am trying to figure out how to achieve the following.

I have a data structure as so in Clojure:

```
  [
    [
      { 
        :key1 "val1",
        :key2 [
                { :type "D", ... },
                { :type "A", ... },
                { :type "B", ...}
              ]
         ...
       }
    ]
  ]
```

What I want to do is keep the same overall data structure with all of it's data. However, I want the objects in "key2" list to be sorted by "type".

After reading some tutorials, I have this much:

```
(doseq [currentList myDataStructure]
  (doseq [currentItem currentList]
    (println (get currentItem :key2))
)))
```

By the way, is `doseq` an alright way to iterate through lists? I see Clojure otherwise does looping through data structures through recursion. Seemed kind of odd to me to add frames to the stack just to iterate through a list.

Comment: calls to `recur` do not add frames to the stack

Comment: A ha! Thanks for letting me know! :D

Comment: `doseq` is a good choice if you only want side effects, but you can do this with a single `doseq`.  You'll need `sort` as well.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with `update-in`:

```
(def x  [[{:key1 "val1",
           :key2 [{:type "D"}
                  {:type "A"}
                  {:type "B"}]}]])

(update-in x [0 0 :key2] (partial sort-by :type))
```

Comment: Not what OP was asking, Michiel, although I originally thought the same thing.

Comment: @Mars I re-read the question and I still think this was the question. "What I want to do is keep the same overall data structure with all of it's data. However, I want the objects in "key2" list to be sorted by "type"."

Comment: Michiel, you understood the question correctly! :D
This is very helpful. I'm now trying to apply update-in dynamically - I mean, rather than specifying indexes (0 0), I'd like to do it for all (0, n).

Comment: Then you probably want to look at https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.walk/postwalk-replace

Comment: @Beebunny please update your question to include this new requirement.

Comment: @Andre What new requirement?

Answer (score 1):

This is perfect use-case for [specter](https://github.com/nathanmarz/specter):

```
(sp/transform [sp/FIRST sp/ALL :key2] (partial sort-by :type)
  [
   [
    {
     :key1 "val1",
     :key2 [{:type "D", :v 1},
            {:type "A", :v 3},
            {:type "B", :v 89}]}
    {
     :key1 "val3",
     :key2 [{:type "Z", :v 10},
            {:type "A", :v 30},
            {:type "B", :v 890}]}
    ]
   ])
;;=> [[{:key1 "val1", :key2 ({:type "A", :v 3} {:type "B", :v 89} {:type "D", :v 1})}

;;     {:key1 "val3", :key2 ({:type "A", :v 30} {:type "B", :v 890} {:type "Z", :v 10})}]]
```